# is there any possibility to simulate the gesture background with code?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, gesture

when an app is in background, is there any way to simulate slide gesture to unlock the phone?

I find a way to simulate it when an app is running:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplicationd] sendAction:@selector(action) to:target :from:webview forEvent:touchEventOrNil];
```

any solutions?

thanks,Zmr.

Comment: What is the point of this operation?  Are you attempting to unlock the device, while it is locked?

Comment: Sorry for not explaning clearly. That's exactly what i want to do --- unlock programmatically. For example, connecting two devices using wifi and one can unlock another with an app, or the device can unlock itself with an app running background at a certain time.